# How to do SQL-like queries in client side browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I've been looking for a way to do complex queries like SQL can perform but totally client side. I know that I can get the exact results that I want from doing SQL queries off of the server and I could even AJAX it so that it looks smooth. However for scaleability, performance, and bandwidth reasons I'd prefer to do this all client side.

Some requirements:

- Wide browser compatibility. Anything that can run jQuery is fine. I'd actually prefer that it be a jQuery plugin.
- Can sort on more than one column. For instance, order by state alphabetically and list all cities alphabetically within each state.
- Can filter results. For instance, the equivalent of "where state = 'CA' or 'NY' or 'TX'".
- Must work completely client side so the user only needs to download a large set of data once and can cut the data however they want without constantly fetching data from the server and would in fact be able to do all queries offline after the initial pull.

I've looked around on stackoverflow and found jslinq but it was last updated in 2009 and has no documentation. I also can't tell if it can do more complex queries like ordering on two different columns or doing "and" or "or" filtering.

I would think that something like this would have been done already. I know HTML5 got started down this path but then hit a roadblock. I just need basic queries, no joins or anything. Does anyone know of something that can do this? Thanks.

Edit: I think I should include a use case to help clarify what I'm looking for.

For example, I have a list of the 5000 largest cities in the US. Each record include Cityname, State, and Population. I would like to be able to download the entire dataset once and populate a JS array with it then, on the client side only, be able to run queries like the following and create a table from the resulting records.

- Ten largest cities in California
- All cities that start with "S" with populations of 1,000,000 or more.
- Largest three cities in California, New York, Florida, Texas, and Illinois and order them alphabetically by state then by population. i.e. California, Los Angeles, 3,792,621; California, San Diego, 1,307,402; California, San Jose, 945,942...etc.

All of these queries would be trivial to do via SQL but I don't want to keep going back and forth to the server and I also want to allow offline use.

Comment: `Wide browser compatibility.` Seems semi-impossible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

It easily meets all your requirements.

Comment: Nice find. You're it can do lots!

Comment: LinqJS acts on the DOM as the data source?  Or on JavaScript objects?  Read over the project home page, but not 100% clear to me.

Comment: I has integration with jQuery and works with its collections also.

Comment: I did already look at this. However (due to lack of any documentation) I cannot tell if it can do more complex queries like cascading sorting. Please see the update to original post for use cases.

Comment: It accepts a function, that you define, to sort with, so you can do anything. It also has convenience methods like "ThenBy" for sorting.

Comment: Confusingly enough, codeplex houses both linqjs and jslinq. The one that I looked at previously was jslinq which has zero documenation (http://jslinq.codeplex.com/documentation). Linqjs doesn't have an extensive documentation page but the home page does link to http://neue.cc/reference.htm which looks comprehensive. I also ended up running across jlinq (http://hugoware.net/Projects/jlinq) just to confuse the issue further. Linqjs looks like it will indeed work fine for the project. Thank you for your help.

Comment: all links are gone. [mojodna/linq.js](https://github.com/mojodna/linq.js) is a mirror of linqjs.codeplex.com. similar projects: [crpietschmann/jslinq](https://github.com/crpietschmann/jslinq) [joaom182/linqjs](https://github.com/joaom182/linqjs) [maurobussini/jslinq](https://github.com/maurobussini/jslinq)

Answer (score 7):

Try [Alasql.js](https://github.com/agershun/alasql). This is a javascript client-side SQL database.

You can do complex queries with joins and grouping, even optimization of joins and where parts. It does not use WebSQL.

Your requirements support:

- Wide browser compatibility - all modern versions of browsers, including mobiles.
- Can sort on more than one column.- Alasql does it with ORDER BY clause.
- Can filter results. - with WHERE clause.
- Must work completely client side so the user only needs to download a large set of data once and can cut the data however they want without constantly fetching data from the server and would in fact be able to do all queries offline after the initial pull. - you can use pure JavaScript (Array.push(), etc.) operations to modify data (do not forget to set table.dirty flag).

Here is a simple example ( play with it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38hj2uwy/10/) ):

```
// Fill table with data
var person = [ 
    { name: 'bill' , sex:'M', income:50000 },
    { name: 'sara' , sex:'F', income:100000 },
    { name: 'larry' , sex:'M', income:90000 },
    { name: 'olga' , sex:'F', income:85000 },
];

// Do the query
var res = alasql("SELECT * FROM ? person WHERE sex='F' AND income > 60000", [person]);
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as the data can fit in memory as an array of objects, you can just use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). For example, say you want to filter products. You want to find all products either below $5 or above $100 and you want to sort by price (ascending), and if there are two products with the same price, sort by manufacturer (descending).  You could do that like this:

```js
var results = products.filter(function(product) {
    // price is in cents
    return product.price < 500 || product.price > 10000;
});
results.sort(function(a, b) {
    var order = a.price - b.price;
    if(order == 0) {
        order = b.manufacturer.localeCompare(a.manufacturer);
    }
    return order;
});
```

For cross-browser compatibility, just shim `filter`.

Comment: Thanks, if I end up having to build something from scratch I'm sure I'd be using those but I'm trying to avoid reinventing the wheel if at all possible.

Comment: @WD-40: Perhaps I misunderstood what you're looking for. I thought you just needed to filter and sort data on the client-side. This does that without really reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Ideally I'd be able to use a SQL like syntax to perform more complex queries (see use cases that I added to original post). At the lowest level I'd imagine that whatever I end up going with will end up using the operations you listed but I'd prefer to use some pre-built generalized framework where I can just plug in values and use operators similar to SQL instead of actually hard coding logic.

Answer (score 0):

[Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) is a pretty good js library which (their words) "gives structure to web applications by providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface."

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can use it to mock up your model and bind event listeners to it. [This](http://backbonetutorials.com/) seems to be a good tutorial to go through some of the base uses for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CanJS](http://canjs.us/). Its a relativelly new library that performs better then Backbone and other and its based on the infamous JavaScript MVC library. In reallity, its the MVC part of the JS MVC with a bit of spices.

You can take a look at this tut by net.tutsplus.com http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/diving-into-canjs-part-3/

It's pretty powerfull and fast. Has features like live binding that make's your life easy.

Answer (score 0):

Coils is a Clojurescript framework which compiles to Javascropt and has client side SQL queries like this:

```
(go
    (log (sql "SELECT * FROM test_table where name = ?" ["shopping"] )))
```

: It is full SQL that is passed to a server side relational database:

https://github.com/zubairq/coils

Answer (score 0):

[sql.js](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js/) is a sqlite client for javascript, based on the original sqlite compiled to WASM.
bundle size is 640KB [wasm](https://sql.js.org/dist/sql-wasm.wasm) + 50KB [js](https://sql.js.org/dist/sql-wasm.js) = 700KB, or 1300KB [asm-js](https://sql.js.org/dist/sql-asm.js)

to compare: [alasql](https://bundlephobia.com/package/alasql@4.3.2) has a bundle size of 440KB

limitation: the full database is stored in memory, so the database should be smaller than 100 MB.
ideally, sql.js should support IndexedDB as an on-disk storage backend, to reduce memory usage

see also

- [absurd-sql](https://github.com/jlongster/absurd-sql) - sql.js with an IndexedDB storage backend. size limit for IndexedDB is around 200 MB
- [Allow hooking into the filesystem and providing a persistent backend (like absurd-sql) sql.js#481](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js/pull/481)
- [Meta VFS for adding storage options sql.js#447](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js/issues/447)